# Why $P^\mu[X_{S+t} \in \Gamma \mid \mathcal{F}_{S+}]=P^\mu[X_{S+t} \in \Gamma \mid X_{S}]=0 \text{ ,} P^\mu\text{-a.s. on } \{S=\infty\}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

For any progressively measurable process $X$ and any optional time $S$ of $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ why do we have that
$$P^\mu[X_{S+t} \in \Gamma \mid \mathcal{F}_{S+}]=P^\mu[X_{S+t} \in \Gamma \mid X_{S}]=0 \text{     ,} P^\mu\text{-a.s. on } \{S=\infty\}$$

This is remark $2.6.4$ in Section 2.6 of Karatzas and Shreve's Brownian Motion and stochastic Calculus

The author mentions at the beginning of the remark that $\{X_{S+t} \in \Gamma \}:= \{X_{S+t} \in \Gamma,S<\infty \}$. 
[image]

Now since $S$ is an $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ optional time, $S$ is $ \mathcal{F}_{S+}$ measurable
So we can write
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P^\mu[X_{S+t} \in \Gamma \mid \mathcal{F}_{S+}] 1_{\{S=\infty\}}=E^\mu[1_{\{X_{S+t} \in \Gamma\}}  1_{\{S=\infty\}} \mid \mathcal{F}_{S+}]=E^\mu[1_{\{X_{S+t} \in \Gamma,S<\infty\}}\}  1_{\{S=\infty\}} \mid \mathcal{F}_{S+}]\\=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
since the product of the two indicators functions is zero everywhere

Is this reasoning correct? If not , could you tell me what is problem. Furthermore how could I show that $P^\mu[X_{S+t} \in \Gamma \mid X_{S}]=0$ on $\{S=\infty \}$. Where is the progressive measurability of $X$ being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think your reasoning of $P^\mu[X_{S+t}\in\Gamma|\mathcal F_{S+}]=0$ on $\{S=\infty\}$ is correct.
2. According to the definition of $\sigma(X_S)$ given in Problem 1.1.17, $\{S=\infty\}\in\sigma(X_S)$. So I think you can apply the same reasoning as above to verify that $P^\mu[X_{S+t}\in\Gamma|X_S]=0$ on $\{S=\infty\}$.
3. To me it seems, therefore, that in asserting 
   $$
    P^\mu[X_{S+t}\in\Gamma|\mathcal F_{S+}]
   =P^\mu[X_{S+t}\in\Gamma|X_S]
   =0\text{  on }\{S=\infty\},
   $$ 
   we don't need the progressive measurability of $X$. I guess that the authors say "for any progressively measurable process $X$" because immediately preceding the remark, they've defined Markov processes as progressively measurable processes satisfying the Markov property (Definitions 2.6.2 and 2.6.3). That is, "for any progressively measurable process $X$," it seems to me, is to say "for any progressively measurable process $X$ (whether it's a Markov process or not)."
    
   $\quad\quad$Markov processes are defined among progressively measurable processes probably in view of Proposition 1.2.18, i.e., to make sure $X_S\in\mathcal F_{S+}$ (the Markov property is an assertion that a conditional expectation given $\mathcal F_{S+}$ be equal to that given $X_S$, so among other things $X_S$ must be measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_{S+}$).

Comment: Thank you for very nice descriptive answer . But when you say I think you are correct do you mean maybe or you are convinced ? What bothers me is that this solution of mine to show that the conditional expectation is zero ( and yours too ) seems to be just a convenience because of the way the authors choose to define  $X_{S+ t} \in \Gamma$  which made me wonder at the first place if my explanation is actually corrected.

Comment: I am not really sure if I understood your last paragraph . First because Markov property talks about conditional probabilities ( and what you said about conditional expectation is just a consequence) . Second I don’t see why would be need  that$ X_S$ is $\mathcal{F}_{S+} measurable ?

Comment: Hi @user3503589 1. I am convinced. If $X1_A=0$, $X$ must be zero on $A$. 2. I don't understand what you mean by "a convenience." A definition is a definition. 3. A conditional probability is a conditional expectation, as you know. And the definition of conditional expectation is such that a version must be measurable with respect to the conditioning $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: By a convenience I meant quite trivial. I am sorry but what I meant was, where do you get ("Markov property is an assertion that the conditional expectation  given $\mathcal{F}_{S+}$ , is equal to that $X_S$") when you explain the reasoning for progressive measurability.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I was simply reading a conditional probability as a conditional expectation whenever I see one. So by "the conditional expectation given $\mathcal F_{S+}$" I meant "the conditional expectation of $1_{X_{S+t}\in\Gamma}$ given $\mathcal F_{S+}$.'' But it's true that the Markov property defined in terms of conditional probabilities is equivalent to the other well-known characterization involving conditional expectations of arbitrary bounded functions (Proposition 2.6.7(e')).

Comment: Yes exactly bounded is the key word here .